# How to pass inputs from a script to command line

Tags: perl, command-line, buffer-overflow, fuzzing

I am a new newbie to scripting, fuzzing, and buffer overflows. I understand the basic concepts behind them though.

I am looking for a way to pass input from a script (I am thinking perl) to a command line.

I am trying to create a fuzzer for a buffer overflow. 
I have a basic C program that takes input from the command line

I need a script that I can pass patterns through to this external program on the command line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `qx{}` operator (otherwise known as backticks), as discussed in `perldoc perlop`.  That makes it easy to capture the output.  Another option is `system` (see `perldoc -f system`).  Another alternative is to open a pipe with `open`, discussed in `perldoc -f open` and `perldoc perlopentut`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file for the inputs, with 11 lines in it (last line is just an empty line to simulate enter key for the last command line input), and then redirect this file to the C program:

```
  ./c_program < file_with_10_inputs
```

You can save the above line as a wrapper script (e.g., auto_exec.sh) and in perl do:

```
  system("sh auto_exec.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to handle the stdin an stdout of the external process, so it's a good idea use a module like [IO::Async](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aAsync%3a%3aProcess), which helps you a lot.